# I got this error while trying to run 'react-native run-android' .I've tired many solutions but non seem to work. I just need a successful build

Tags: javascript

BUILD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'Rend'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.5.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.5.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.pom'.
  >   No such host is known (dl.google.com)
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.5.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.pom'.
  >   No such host is known (jcenter.bintray.com)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\user\Rend\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\user\Rend\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\user\Rend\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\user\Rend\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

try open emulator manual with android studio and run npx react-native run-android